# What is an example of a localization of a non-simple, nilpotent space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, localization

Im reading "More concise algebraic topology" from May and Ponto. They describe how to localize nilpotent spaces at a set of primes T, but I wasn´t able to find any computations of such a localizations for nilpotent spaces that are not simple spaces. Does anyone have an example?

Comment: Try [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116051/localizations-of-non-nilpotent-spaces).